# How can I upload a file to a Synology diskstation with PHP

Tags: php, file, curl, upload, synology

I want to post to a Synology Disksation and upload a file with PHP. The Synology's API gives me an interface that I want to call with PHP. See the documentation below.

https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/DeveloperGuide/Synology_File_Station_API_Guide.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A111%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C69%2C711%2C0%5D

Here is my code, which I use for the post:

```
    <?php
        $params = array(
           'path' => '/home/upload',
           'create_parents' => 'true',
           'overwrite' => 'true',
           'api' => 'SYNO.FileStation.Upload',
           'version' => 2,
           'method' => 'upload'
           '_sid' => [id of session after authenticate],
           'file[]' => "@".path_to_file
        );

        $ch = curl_init();

        $BODY = http_build_query($params);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ip_of_diskstation:5000/entry.cgi');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $BODY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        var_dump($result);
    ?>
```

This call works, but the diskstation gives me the following JSON.

```
{"error":{"code":401},"success":false}
```

According to the documentation, there is a "Unknown error of file operation". Also, using "file_get_contents (path to file)" instead of "@".path_to_file gives me the same error from the diskstation.

How can I post a file and parameters to a synology diskstation?

Comment: `401` status code usually means `Unauthorized`. Are you confident in the value of `_sid`? Do you need to enable something on the Diskstation before using this API?

Comment: I get the JSON {"data": "sid": "5RXTvhuc0fuuY1420LUN005590"}, "success": true} after calling "http://[ip_of_diskstation]:5000/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&version=2&method=login&account=[username]&passwd=[pass]&session=DownloadStation&format=cookie". This "sid" I use for the upload call in the code above. 

In the documentation of the Synology API, 401 has a different meaning than in HTTP.
https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/DeveloperGuide/Synology_File_Station_API_Guide.pdf#page=9&zoom=auto,-278,769

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add _sid in your web api url like http://ip_of_diskstation:5000/entry.cgi?_sid=

I make it work using nodejs request library.

Below is the code:

```
            let r = request.post( { url: `${web_url}/entry.cgi?_sid=${sid}` }, ( err, response, body ) => {
                return callback( err, response );
            });
            let form = r.form();
            form.append( 'api', 'SYNO.FileStation.Upload');
            form.append( 'version', '2');
            form.append( 'method', 'upload' );
            form.append( 'overwrite', 'false' );
            form.append( 'path', '<shared folder path>');
            form.append( 'create_parents', 'true' );
            form.append( '_sid', sid );
            form.append( 'file', fs.createReadStream( file ), { 'filename' : <filename without the path>});
```

Regards,

Felix

Answer (score 0):

You get :

```
"{"error":{"code":401},"success":false}"
```

Because **the official document is wrong**.

See [Upload file through FileStation upload api](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/131819) for details.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the url that you used in **CURLOPT_URL** needs to be updated. Also the file that is in the **$params** needs to be updated.

Some side notes. Make sure your settings for the user's SID has permissions set properly. Also make sure you updated the **$_FILES["uploadfile"]** to include whatever name you used within the input element of the form (instead of uploadfile, which I used).

See this [github link](https://github.com/alexiscn/SynologyKit/issues/9#issuecomment-569432549) for where I found my reference. Postman helped me duplicate this in PHP.

```
$sid = '_sid=[YOURSID]';
$url = 'HOSTNAME/webapi/entry.cgi?' . $sid;
$SynologySharedPath = 'FILEPATH';

$params = array(
  'api' => 'SYNO.FileStation.Upload',
  'version' => '2',
  'method' => 'upload',
  'path' => $SynologySharedPath,
  'create_parents' => 'true',
  'overwrite' => 'true',
  'file' => new \CurlFile($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["uploadfile"]["type"], $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'])
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);

    $curlresponse = json_decode($result, true);
```